# How to add rectangle corner angles in 2D canvas?

Tags: canvas, html5-canvas

[image]

I am working on 2D Canvas and I want to add this corner angles in each corner of rectangle(Please see Image) and this rectangle size is not fixed I can change rectangle size by dragging mouse button, I already did flexible rectangle. Please can anybody help me, How to add those corners and it should be flexible according to rectangle size.

```
 function draw() {
        ctx.fillStyle = "#6E97B1";  
        width += deltaMove.x;
        height += deltaMove.y;
        var CrosshairSize = 6;
        ctx.strokeStyle = '#00BEFE';  
        ctx.globalAlpha = 0.3;
        ctx.lineWidth = 1;
        ctx.fillRect(startposition.x, startposition.y, width, height);
        ctx.strokeRect(startposition.x + (1 + width / 2), startposition.y + (height / 2) - (CrosshairSize / 2), 1, CrosshairSize);
        ctx.strokeRect(startposition.x + (1 + width / 2) - (CrosshairSize / 2), startposition.y + (height / 2), CrosshairSize, 1); }
```

Answer (score 1):

Think you may want something like the following,

```js
//================================================================
// The drawBox function
// Arguments
// x,y : top left of the box
// w,h : width and height. If you have a coordinate the width and height 
//       can be calculated mouseX - x, mouseY - y  where x, and y are the 
//       top left of the box.
// crosshairSize :   for one arm. Total size is crosshairSize * 2 + detailWidth
// detailWidth : of detail
// fill : background of rect fill colour
// detailCol :  colour
function drawBox(x, y, w, h, crosshairSize, detailWidth, fill, detailCol) {
        function drawCross(x,y,s,w){ // draw crosshair s is size, w is width
          const hw = w / 2; // half width
          ctx.beginPath();
          ctx.lineTo(x - hw, y - hw);
          ctx.lineTo(x - hw, y - s);
          ctx.lineTo(x + hw, y - s);
          ctx.lineTo(x + hw, y - hw);
          ctx.lineTo(x + s, y - hw);
          ctx.lineTo(x + s, y + hw);
          ctx.lineTo(x + hw, y + hw);
          ctx.lineTo(x + hw, y + s);
          ctx.lineTo(x - hw, y + s);
          ctx.lineTo(x - hw, y + hw);
          ctx.lineTo(x - s, y + hw);
          ctx.lineTo(x - s, y - hw);
          ctx.closePath();
          ctx.fill()
        }
        function drawCorner(x,y,dx,dy,s,w){ // draw crosshair s is size, w is width
                                            // dx and dy are directions        
          const hw = w / 2; // half width
          ctx.beginPath();
          ctx.lineTo(x,y);
          ctx.lineTo(x + dx * s, y);
          ctx.lineTo(x + dx * s, y + dy * w);
          ctx.lineTo(x + dx * w, y + dy * w);
          ctx.lineTo(x + dx * w, y + dy * s);
          ctx.lineTo(x , y + dy * s);
          ctx.closePath();
          ctx.fill();
        }
        ctx.fillStyle = fill;  
        ctx.fillRect(x,y,w,h);
        ctx.fillStyle = detailCol;  
        drawCross(x + w / 2, y + h / 2,crosshairSize,detailWidth);
        drawCorner(x , y ,1, 1, crosshairSize * 2 ,detailWidth);
        drawCorner(x + w , y ,-1, 1, crosshairSize * 2 ,detailWidth);
        drawCorner(x + w, y + h ,-1, -1, crosshairSize * 2 ,detailWidth);
        drawCorner(x , y + h,1, -1, crosshairSize * 2 ,detailWidth);
        
}

// end of function
// ===========================================







// rest of code is just to animate 
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

function mainLoop(time){
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,300,150);
  var w = Math.abs(Math.sin(time / 10000) * 110) + 20;
  var h = Math.abs(Math.sin(time / 3791) * 45) + 20 ;


  // Calling the drawBox function
  drawBox(150-w,75-h,w*2,h* 2,8,4,"#6E97B1",'#00BEFE');



  requestAnimationFrame( mainLoop);

}
 requestAnimationFrame( mainLoop);



// Code monkey pay 2 peanuts and a banana please.
```

```html
<canvas id = "canvas"></canvas>
```

...getting the low quality JPEG artifacts would take 3 extra lines of code if you need it. :P

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I want. Thank you soooo much :)

Comment: Please can you give me little advice, How to stop this moving box animation. I want to do exactly same but when I will drag by cursor point in mouse down event and this box should be disappear when mouse up event.

Comment: Thanks in advance :)

Comment: @Mhd I have added some more comments to the code to make it clearer. There is no room in the comments to explain how to animate user input. Try searching Stackoverflow it is likely someone has already asked how to do that. If you cant find an example, ask another question. But please note we are not a code writing service, so do include what code you have tried in the question.

Comment: Yes sure!! Thank you for your help :)